# ARKit Scene view blocked when go back from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, arkit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am facing to an issue when I come back from a `MFMailComposeViewController` to `ARSCNView` the scene is blocked, I can still interact with 3D models (`hitTesting`) on blocked screen.

Do you have any solution?

YM

Comment: What do you mean blocked?

Comment: @JoshRobbins The screen is locked when I come back from a `MFMailComposeViewController` to `ARSCNView`: the video does not restart...

Comment: Your going to need to paste some code then :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins I solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. On my `ARSCNView` Controller, I did not reset configuration on the function `viewDidAppear`.

To solve it:

```
override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Prevent the screen from being dimmed to avoid interuppting the AR experience.
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

    // Start the `ARSession`.
    resetTracking()
}


func resetTracking() {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```